# Can't update due to Azure packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I am currently trying to run a simple `sudo apt upgrade` on my Ubuntu box but it would seem there are Azure packages that are queued to be removed but are blocking the upgrade process.

The error message I am getting is as follows:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-5.0.0-1025-azure : Depends: linux-modules-5.0.0-1025-azure but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-5.0.0-1027-azure : Depends: linux-modules-5.0.0-1027-azure but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Now I've tried running the following commands to try and clear this with no luck:

```
sudo dpkg -r linux-image-5.0.0-1027-azure
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-5.0.0-1027-azure
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt clean
```

None of these fixed the issue. Does anyone possibly know how on Earth I can fix this?

Comment: "Broken packages" does not mean *corrupted* or *damaged* packages. It means you have added a wrong-version package that has broken apt's ability to logically determine your intent. This usually comes from a non-Ubuntu or wrong-version source or a PPA. Uninstall the wrong-version packages and delete their source. Then apt will work again.

Comment: @user535733 - If i try ```apt remove {package}``` it is just giving me another error: ```error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-1025-azure (--remove)```

Comment: Stop trying to remove packages that aren't installed. That gets you nowhere. You will make faster progress if you talk to us about your non-Ubuntu sources, wrong-version sources, or PPAs. Easy way: Add the complete output of `sudo apt update` to your question above.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working by going into the sources.list file 
Replaced all instances of **bionic** and **focal** with **impish**

and ran all the commands again.

then it worked